# Finding minimum, maximum and average values for nested lists?

Tags: python, list

So I have these lists:

```
Player1 = ["Ryan", 24, 19]
Player2 = ["Jamie", 22, 24]
Player3 = ["Alicia", 17, 15]
Player4 = ["Dominique", 13, 11]
Player5 = ["Michael", 18, 23]

PlayerList = [Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5]
```

The format is [Player's name, first round score, second round score]

How to write a code to find the highest value, as well as the average for first and second scores respectively?

EDIT: I think I might need to print the 'name of the players with the highest score' instead of the 'highest score' but I don't know how to do that :\

Comment: Just saying, but it might be time to write a `Player` class.

Comment: What if there is a tied highest score...?

Comment: ...or at least a tuple, it's conceptually more fitting than a list.

Answer (score 9):

Highest value:

```
max(max(p[1:]) for p in PlayerList)
```

Lowest value:

```
min(min(p[1:]) for p in PlayerList)
```

Averages for each player::

```
[float(p[1] + p[2]) / 2 for p in PlayerList]
```

ETA: Per your comment, the name of the player with the highest score:

```
max(PlayerList, key=lambda p: max(p[1:]))[0]
```

Comment: You could just call `max(max(p[1:]) for p in PlayerList)`.

Comment: True, and as a generator that would be (slightly) faster

Comment: @KennyTM Is there any way that I can print the player's name who has the highest score as well?

Answer (score 1):

Max and min:

```
>>> max(PlayerList, key=lambda p: max(p[1:]))
['Ryan', 24, 19]
>>> min(PlayerList, key=lambda p: min(p[1:]))
['Dominique', 13, 11]
```

Average is a bit dirtier:

```
>>> [(p[0], sum(p[1:]) / 2.) for p in PlayerList]
[('Ryan', 21.5), ('Jamie', 23.0), ('Alicia', 16.0), ('Dominique', 12.0), ('Michael', 20.5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the players with the highest and lowest score in any round:

```
(max_score, max_player) = max( (max(a, b), player) for (player, a, b) in players )
(min_score, min_player) = min( (min(a, b), player) for (player, a, b) in players )
```

If instead you want the players with the highest and lowest total scores, simply replace `max(a, b)` and `min(a, b)` with `a + b`.

Note that this picks a single best/worst player, even if there's a tie.

To find averages of the first and second scores:

```
avg_round1 = float(sum( a for (_, a, _) in players )) / len(players)
avg_round2 = float(sum( b for (_, _, b) in players )) / len(players)
```